# Text content not completely writing in the csv file

Tags: php, html, file, file-upload, file-io

I am writing a **CSV** file through the html form, which posts huge amounts of text content through **textarea**.

However the whole text is not getting created within the **csv**, using this PHP code for creating **csv** file :

```
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
        foreach($_POST as $value)
        {
            fputcsv($fp, $value);
        }
        fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the name of your textarea is "content", use this

```
if( isset($_POST['content']) ) {
    file_put_contents( 'file.csv', $_POST['content'] );
}
```

if the $_POST['content'] is a valid CSV content

Comment: there are also other post variables not only "text content" one

Comment: Ok, Post your form, so we'll know what you're dealing with :)

Comment: <form action="#" method="POST" > 
 <div class="input_field">
  <div class="input_content">
    <label>Title</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="Title" size="48">
  </div>
  <div class="input_content">
    <label>Description</label>
    <textarea name="desc" cols="60" rows="16"></textarea>
  </div>
 </div> 
 <div class="button">
  <input id="submit" class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" name="">  
 </div>
</form>

Comment: So, you have a form with title and content. What do you need to write in your CSV file. How do you imagine it, as an example?

Answer (score 0):

This code will produce a CSV file

```
 <?php
 /* If file has not been created this will form title header(Use only once)
 file_put_contents('file.csv',"Title,Description\r\n", FILE_APPEND);
 */
```

The remaining code will add a new line every time the form is posted

```
 if( isset($_POST['Title'],$_POST['desc']) ) {
 file_put_contents('file.csv',$_POST['Title'].",". $_POST['desc']."\r\n", FILE_APPEND); 
 }
 ?>
```